# Microsoft Word - While using different font size, how to keep the same left space before letter to have proper vertical alignment

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, typography

In Microsoft Word, if you have two line with different font size they will have a different space at the beginning of the line. The bigger the font size, the bigger the left space.

This is not specific to MS Word and consistent with most text editor.

But how this can be avoided? For example if you have title and a subtitle just below. A workaround would be to play with the indentation, but is their a better way?

[image: an example of word adding more left space when the font is bigger]

Comment: This is likely to depend on the font and the character.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon certainly, I tried with different font and had similar space. Font like Arial does have the problem.

Comment: I understand, but any solution is going to be specific to the font and size. You could look at the Advance field which can place text anywhere. https://word.tips.net/T000547_Understanding_the_ADVANCE_Field.html

Comment: The Advance field is quiet interesting. Thanks.